# Delete item from gridview

Tags: android, image, gridview, gallery, delete-file

I know that here are many answers how to delete items, but I can't make it work. It show errors. Can you look? I added in adapter remove(position), but I think it works wrongly.
So I want after using `onItemLongClickListener` to delete file and its thumbnail too.

Main:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    final ThumbnailAdapter thumbnails = new ThumbnailAdapter(this);
    grid.setAdapter(thumbnails);
    grid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {

                final String imgPath = thumbnails.getImagePath(position);
                File file = new File(imgPath);                  
                 file.delete();
                 thumbnails.remove(position);
                 thumbnails.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 grid.invalidateViews();
                 grid.setAdapter(thumbnails);
                return true;


            }
    });
```

Adapter:

```
public class ThumbnailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Context required for performing queries
private final Context mContext;

// Cursor for thumbnails
private final Cursor cursor;
private final int imgId;
private final int imgData;
private final int count;

public ThumbnailAdapter(Context c) {
    this.mContext = c;

    // Get list of all images, sorted by last taken first
    final String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
    };
    cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
    );
    imgId = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    imgData = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    count = cursor.getCount();
    Log.d("ThumbnailAdapter", count + " images found");
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    final Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
            mContext.getContentResolver(),
            cursor.getInt(imgId), 
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
            null
    );
    imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    Log.d("ThumbnailAdapter", "render: " + cursor.getString(imgData));
    return imageView;

}

public String getImagePath(int position) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    return cursor.getString(imgData);
}
public void remove(int position) {
    remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: after  launcing application, when i make onlongitemclicklistener, it;s shows error

Answer (score 0):

I guess its stack overflow. your remove method in the adapter is recursive forever.
Instead of deleting file youself ask content resolver to remove it. and the reload data.
you dont have to call grid.setAdapter(thumbnails)  again in the click listner

Answer (score 0):

Check this line please though :

```
file.delete();
             thumbnails.remove(position);
```

You are deleting your file first and then removing it from adapter. It should be other way around. You reset your adapter then delete the actual file. Your thumbnail is deleted while still being attached to the adapter.

Comment: hey, i saw at your page that you are android developer. Can you help me in one programm? I have a programm which search all image (with MediaStore.Images.Media) and shows them in gridview(their thumbnails). But i need to show folders(which contain that images) and show them in gridview. after clicking on them, they should show me picture. Can you help me to remake mine project??

Comment: dont do that MediaStore.Images ?? It will result in outof memory really quick instead use lazyloading for gridview using universal image loader

Comment: it don;t result outofmemory, cuz in gridview i show thumbnails(not images). it works normally. only first lauching is toooo looong. so can u help with makeing so gallery like i said>?? with folders